# How to zip a database file in winrt app?

Tags: c#, windows-8

I have a sqlite database file "test.db".
I want to zip this file through C# code.
But when I am trying to do this, I am getting "Access is denied" exception.

Here is the code that I am using :

```
byte[] buffer = WindowsRuntimeBufferExtensions.ToArray(await FileIO.ReadBufferAsync(fileToCompress));
ZipArchiveEntry entry = zipArchive.CreateEntry(fileToCompress.Name);
using (Stream entryStream = entry.Open())
{
    await entryStream.WriteAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
}
```

Can any one tell how I can zip a database file in winrt app through C# code ?

Comment: Which line is giving you the error?

Comment: byte[] buffer = WindowsRuntimeBufferExtensions.ToArray(await FileIO.ReadBufferAsync(fileToCompress));

Answer (score 0):

I'm away from my pc here so I cannot try this but:

Windows RT apps cannot access files in the system outside the windows-user folders (Videos, Music, Documents, Downloads, Pictures and USB units) from code. This is only possible by using a file picker (this way, the user is responsible for the file selection).

If you try to do so from code, you get an exception.

Have you tried that piece of code having the "test.db" file inside the current user "Documents" folder?

The other idea that comes to mind, is to check that the Database is not opened and has been detached from your DBA.